# Long walking trails in Europe with accommodation enroute

Tags: europe, accommodation, walking

What waymarked walking trails in Europe allow you to stay in hotels/guest houses/b&bs every night along the trails?

I'm looking specifically for way-marked trails that you can walk along for 5 or 6 days without having to carry camping equipment, and instead stay in hotels every night.

I know that there are hundreds of walking trails in Europe, but the majority of them, you can only walk for at most 2 or 3 days before you have to go more than a day's worth of walking to get to the next hotel.

What walking trails exist that allow you to do this?

Comment: Any specific trails you are interested in?  Any specific hotels?

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad.  Feel free to edit it and flag for reopening.  There are over 30 countries in Europe, with thousands of hotels, walking trains or roads.  You really need to narrow it down - country, direction, type of scenery perhaps? Looking forward to the update.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is too broad and I think there is a perfect example for a way, e.g. the Santiago de Compostela (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago_de_Compostela)

Comment: I do not think this is too broad, it's actually quite specific... Of all the walking trails in europe, which subset have a continuous section of 6 or 7 days with night stops, where every night stop is at a location where there exists a hotel or guesthouse.

Comment: thanks for your updates and edits, I've added some as well and reworded the title - let me know if that's not ok.  Reopening now.  I think the fact that you mention very few exist that are more than a couple of days will help narrow it down quite a lot. @Roflcoptr - perhaps turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 6):

In Spain you have the Camino de Santiago. This is what I wrote about it in [another Travel question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/good-locations-in-spain-for-hiking-nature-architecture-and-photo-opportunitie):

> You are looking to walk the Camino de Santiago. It joins hiking,
>   nature, historic architecture, photo opportunities and is very cheap
>   (eat about 6-8 € per meal and sleep 4-8 €). Additionally, you'll know
>   the real Spain, meet interesting people (mainly Spanish, but you can
>   find people from around the world and you will complete one of the
>   mythical mid age routes.
>
> Depending on the time you have you can start from one city or other.
>   For instance if you have 2-3 weeks you can start walking from Leon.

[image: Licensed under CC by mariosp at Flickr]

*Image licensed under CC by mariosp at [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mariosp/6332546557/)*

You'll find cheap accomodation in nearly every village you cross. You have a lot of guides (printed or [online](http://www.caminodesantiago.me.uk/)) that will help you to book hostels (but, believe me, if you are not going on peak season it is not necessary at all).

Depending on your time and interests you could start walking on one or another place. The best is you read any guide to know where is the best place to start walking for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can find informations on french [GR-Info](http://www.gr-infos.com/) site. It is about long distance footpaths  in France, including contact info on accomodations.

For instance, GR-10 crosses the Pyrénées mountains from Atlantic Ocean to Mediterranean Sea, or GR-20 around Corsica.

Comment: for the GR20, this is particularly good... http://corsica.forhikers.com/gr20

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Norwegian Trekking Association](http://www.turistforeningen.no/english/), which has cabins all over Norway. Joining the association is not very expensive, and it gives you cheaper prices and priority on bunks when cabins are crowded.

The association has some [suggested trips](http://www.turistforeningen.no/english/trip.php?fo_id=3987), where you can walk from cabin to cabin.