# Is there in the world trails like Israel National Trail?

Tags: israel, walking

In Israel there is something called *[Israel National Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_National_Trail)* (**Hebrew**: שביל ישראל‎, Shvil Yisra'el). It is a trail that goes from the north of the country to the south in about 1000 km. A trail where you will go through all types of natures and a great way to visit and learn about Israel. The trail is marked with three stripes (white, blue, and orange), and takes an average of 45-60 days to complete.

[image]

[image: svhil]

In addition, there are places to stay for a small amount of money somewhere in the middle of the trail. Even some few places for free. This is the case when you don't use tent.

I would want to know if there are similar things in different countries, where there is a *built* trail, that travelers take. Obviously, if you can give examples where there it's secure.

Comment: Nearly all countries got trails, some very long. I think you need to be a bit more specific. What do you mean with build trail? One extremely long trail, although not marked, with cheap or free places to stay, is the pilgrimage to Santiago de Compostella in Spain.

Comment: @J.Constantine I would want to know about marked ones.

Comment: For example, the [Appalachian Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_Trail) in the US. But this is just asking for a long list of items with rather loose criteria, and that isn't a good match for the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: As noted, almost every developed country, and many developing ones, big enough to have multi-day hikes has them. Some famous ones include the [Camino de Santiago](http://www.spain.info/en/que-quieres/rutas/grandes-rutas/camino-santiago/), the [Inca Trail](http://www.incatrailperu.com/), the [Milford Track](http://www.doc.govt.nz/milfordtrack), the [John Muir Trail](http://www.pcta.org/discover-the-trail/john-muir-trail/j), and the [Everest Base Camp Trek](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Everest_Base_Camp_Trek). But there are hundreds, maybe thousands, to choose from.

Comment: Agreed, this is far too broad. There are probably thousands of such trails. There's a [whole network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_long-distance_paths) in Europe. So many trails in the US you need [top 10 lists](http://www.theguardian.com/travel/2015/jan/19/top-10-long-distance-hiking-trails-us-california-oregon-texas).

Comment: @J.Constantine The trail to Santiago de Compostela *is* marked. See a few markers here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camino_de_Santiago

Comment: @PichiWuana Don't be sorry. It's a good question, if perhaps a bit broad.

Comment: @PichiWuana There's also this: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5875/long-walking-trails-in-europe-with-accommodation-enroute?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A broad question, but not an unreasonable one. Perhaps the better question would be on what resources are available to identify similar walking trails.

And, behold, there is a lovely map over at http://hiking.waymarkedtrails.org/, showing that Europe is chockablock with marked trails.